# How to track location by gps with php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, gps

I have tried to track my client location by geoIp but in my country this data is not relevant. 
How can i do this for mobile device by geo gps function in php?

Comment: HTML5 Geolocation API ???

Comment: thanks but i need it in server side php